# What is the definition of infinite union or infinite intersection of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

While following my courses, I have encountered many times the idea of an intersection or union of an infinite number of sets. For example in my analysis course we have defined $C^\infty$ as: $$C^\infty := \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} C^n $$
Or in my algebra course my professor has stated that the union of a countable number of countable sets is countable. But while the definition of an infinite sum was given to us clearly, for example $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\alpha ^ i = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha ^ i$, no one ever defined such a concept for set operations. Where can I find more on these concepts?

Comment: Consider the infinite sequence of sets $C_1, C_2, C_3, \cdots.$  Now define the set sequence $\langle B_n\rangle$ by $B_1 = C_1, B_{n+1} = B_n \cap C_{n+1}.$  Then the set $B_\infty$ consists of all elements $x$, and only those elements $x$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, x \in B_n$.

Comment: The definitions are $$x\in \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C^n\Leftrightarrow \forall n\in \Bbb N, x\in C^n\\ x\in \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}C^n\Leftrightarrow\exists n\in\Bbb N, x\in C^n$$

Comment: The definitions are in most textbooks that cover the elementary concepts of set theory. Wikipedia covers them too [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_intersections), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Arbitrary_unions).